# Cannot start Julia v1.5.0 on ubuntu 18.04, but v1.0.4

Tags: installation, julia

I was attempting to install Julia 1.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the 64-bit GPG from https://julialang.org/downloads/

and I followed instructions from Linux and FreeBSD from

https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/

I have a directory named `julia-1.5.0` set up in my ~ directory and I changed in my `~/.profile` to set up the PATH variable like the instructions say, but whenever I type `julia` into terminal, I startup v1.0.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I am accidently using the linux build of julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show us your `PATH` as the new directory *must* come before the existing one, *i.e* add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question.

Also, try `which julia` resulting on my machine in `/usr/bin/julia` which is correct as I have no other version.